# Error in C with word counting program using switch statement

Tags: c, memory

I am having trouble counting the number of words that the user enters using a switch statement. I want to ensure that multiple presses of the keyboard (ASCII,32) do not count for multiple words. As you can see, I have a memory variable that stores the previous keyboard press, and I want to only count a word when the current keyboard press is a space, and the previous press (i.e. the memory variable is not a space). The logic makes perfect sense to me; however, the code does not seem to work. Could someone please explain where my flaw in logic is? Thanks.

```
// 1.4 Exercise 1: output the amount of characters, number of words and number of newlines typed by the user 
// Note that the escape command on my mac is ENTER then COMMAND Z
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long characters = -1; // to exit program on my mac you must press COMMAND+Z 
    long newlines = 0;
    long words = 1; // assume the document starts with a word 

    printf("Type stuff! To exit type CTRL+D (some computers use CTRL+Z then space)\n");

    int i = 0;
    int memory = 32; //stores the previous keyboard press 


    while (i != EOF) // characters will continue counting as long as the escape sequence is not entered 
    {
        i = getchar(); //Assign the integer output of the buffered getchar() function to i 

        if (i != 10)
        {
            characters++;
        }

        switch (i)
        {
        case 10: // for enter key press
        {
            newlines++;
            break; // exit switch (each character is unique) 
        }
        case 32: // for space 
        {
            if (memory != 32) // if the previous character press was not a space, then words++
            {
                words++;
            }
            memory = i; // stores the previous keyboard press
            break; // exit switch (each character is unique) 
        }
        default: break; //exit switch is the default action if the previous switches are not true 
        }
    }

    printf("%d characters were typed\n", characters);
    printf("%d words were typed\n", words);
    printf("%d lines were typed\n", newlines);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your code, `memory` can't be anything but 32, because you set it to `i` only in the case where `i` is 32. Move that to after the `switch` statement, so that the `memory` is always the previous `i`.

Comment: (Oh, and please change the title to something that describes the problem better. Although your variable is called `memory`,  this is not what I'd call a memory error.)

Comment: My bad, I only started programming a week ago.

Comment: No hard feelings. The new title is much clearer, thanks for changing it.

Comment: And thank you. My program is fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

You are only updating the value of memory when inside of your case statement when i = 32. With this, the value of memory will always be 32. Instead, you should update the value of memory after the switch statement is closed. i.e.

```
switch(i)
{
    /* code here */
}
memory = i
```

As a side note, it will make your code more readable and aid portability if you don't hard-code the ascii values of characters into your switch statement. You can instead write them using the character.

```
switch(i) 
{
    case '\n':
        /* code */
        break;
    case ' ':
        /* code */
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You unconditionally have to store the previous character:

```
 memory = i;
```

Also, think about the corner-cases, e.g. what happens when there's only a single word (without spaces) in a line. As you can see, not only spaces can separate words.